# Accepting empty strings in C

Tags: c, input

My program can either accept a number of any length or empty input. However, if the input is empty (space or newline), the program continues to wait for an input. I also tried `fgets` but if space/newline is pressed, it still waits for more input that is not a space/newline before closing.

Simpified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%i",&num);
    printf("%i",num);
}
```

Input:

```
363792
```

Output:

```
363792
```

Desired:

Input:

Output:

I'm new to *C* and am having a very hard time accomplishing this.

What tried using fgets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    int n;
    char s[20];

    fgets(s,20,stdin);
    n = atoi(s);

    printf("%i",n);
}
```

Edit: Turns out I was not compiling the code right. So every time I tried to make changes, it just looked at the original code using scanf.

Comment: Means,Do you want to ignore empty inputs (space or newline)?

Comment: If you have no input this code output 0, is it your desire?

Comment: The `scanf` does not work as expected because `%d` skips leading whitespace characters.

Comment: I switched to fgets() and it works.  I was compiling the code wrong so the program was still using scanf from my very first attempt.

Comment: With scanf() and with fgets(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I also tried fgets but if space/newline is pressed, it still waits for more input that is not a space/newline before closing.

Firstly `fgets` will work in this case. If you had shown us what exactly you tried to do using `fgets()` then answer to this question would have much narrow or very specific.

I tried to do the same using `fgets()` and below is the code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a number: ");

    fgets (string, 100, stdin);
    /* Here remove  the trailing new line char; not required unless you are trying to print the string */
    string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Num is %d\n", atoi(string));

    return 0;
}
```

If there is no input or just enter or space and enter, then number printed will be zero and fgets() will not wait until you enter a valid number.

Also check this on why you **shouldn't use gets**. [Do not use gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: I had tried code like this earlier. I just didn't realize that new code was not being compiled :( Thank you for the help!  It works!

Comment: `string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';` incorrectly truncates when there is no `'\n'`.  It is undefined behavior should the first character be an rare embedded `'\0'`.  Better to use  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359

Comment: regarding this line: `string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';` this will not work correctly in all cases for two reasons.  1) as mentioned by chux, if no newline then the line will be corrupted.  2) if running under windows/dos, (where a newline is actually two characters)  this will not removed the newline, just corrupt it.  Suggest using something like: `char * offset = strstr( string, "\n" );  if (NULL != offset) *offset = '\0';`

Comment: @user3629249: Agreed. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

According to definition of [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

> The function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character.

So you can not get your desired result using `scanf()`. 
As **gets()  is not safe and it misbehaves badly**. you can use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to get input and convert it to integer if you need using `atoi()`.

Here sample code you can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int num;
    char ch[100];
    fgets(ch, sizeof ch, stdin);
    if (strlen(ch)>1&& ch[strlen(ch)-1] == '\n')
    {
        ch[strlen(ch)-1] = '\0';
        num = atoi(ch);
        printf("%i\n", num);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. [Don't ever use `gets()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/1679849)

Comment: @Enzo Ferber Please clarify "needs a space before the type format in order to ignore whitespaces".  Certainly `scanf(" %d", ...)`  and `scanf("%d", ...)` equally scan `int`.

Comment: @chux Yes, I thought I had removed that.

Answer (score 5):

You should read the input character by character and stop reading if the read character is not a number:

```
char ch;
while(1)
{
    ch=getchar();
    if(isdigit(ch))
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ch` should be an `int` as `getchar` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

alright, you do not understand what scanf() does, it goes and scans entire input string and looks for special characters like %d, %f, %s and until it does not get what is in string it will wait.

```
scanf("%d %d", a, b);
```

will get done only when you enter 2 integer values, if you press space it does not count as integer value so it will ignore it.